# Why does a Parent table not have a matching Primary or Unique key, when a foreign key is referenced to the parent table?

Tags: sql, db2, iseries-navigator

So I'm having this issue where my table's foreign key is not referencing the previous table correctly. I am coding in DB2 for IBM i (using the older language where COLLECTIONS is being used instead of SCHEMA----its part of the curriculum at my college)

the exact error message is:

> SQL State: 42890
>   Vendor Code: -573
>   Message: [SQL0573] Table EMPLOYEE in UMALIK5 does not have a matching parent key. Cause . . . . . :   A referencing column list was specified in the FOREIGN KEY clause for constraint CAMPUS_FK in UMALIK5. The parent table EMPLOYEE in UMALIK5 does not have a matching PRIMARY or UNIQUE key. If the file is partitioned, the access path of the parent file must be non-partitioned. The constraint cannot be added. Recovery  . . . :   Do one of the following and try the request again: -- Specify a table in the FOREIGN KEY clause that has a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key that matches the referencing column list. -- Change the referencing column list to match the definition of the PRIMARY or UNIQUE key defined on the parent table. -- If the parent file is partitioned, add a non-partitioned access path.
>   Processing ended because the highlighted statement did not complete successfully

The error I looked up on IBM's support page and it was even more confusing than this.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE UMALIK5.POSITION (
POSNCODE VARCHAR (10) CONSTRAINT UMALIK5.POSITION_PK PRIMARY KEY,
POSNDESC VARCHAR (50));

SELECT * FROM UMALIK5.SYSTABLES;
SELECT * FROM UMALIK5.SYSCOLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'EMPLOYEE';
CREATE TABLE UMALIK5.EMPLOYEE (
EMP_NUM VARCHAR (10) CONSTRAINT UMALIK5.EMPLOYEE_PK PRIMARY KEY,
EMP_F_NAME VARCHAR (50),
EMP_L_NAME VARCHAR (50),
MANAGER_NUM VARCHAR (10),
SUPERVISOR_CODE VARCHAR (10),
PAYRATE VARCHAR (20),
POSNCODE VARCHAR (10),
HIREDATE VARCHAR (50),
CONSTRAINT UMALIK5.EMPLOYEE_FK FOREIGN KEY (POSNCODE)
REFERENCES UMALIK5.POSITION(POSNCODE));

CREATE TABLE UMALIK5.CAMPUS (
CAMPUS_ID VARCHAR (10) CONSTRAINT UMALIK5.CAMPUS_PK PRIMARY KEY,
CAMPUS_NAME VARCHAR (30),
MANAGER_NUM VARCHAR (10),
CONSTRAINT UMALIK5.CAMPUS_FK FOREIGN KEY (MANAGER_NUM)
REFERENCES UMALIK5.EMPLOYEE(MANAGER_NUM));
```

I'm at a loss as to what I need to do, the table Employee creates just fine when I run my DB2 script, but for some reason the CAMPUS table does not.

What am I doing wrong?

thank you for your help.

Comment: Not sure if it's the cause of your error, but a normalized database will reference the primary key of the parent table when setting up foreign keys.  You are not doing that.

Comment: In my new cumulative design, i have this

Campus [CampusID, CampusName, Mnger#]
FK Mnger# --> Employee

however in my Employee table I have posncode fk to position table....so that's what I tried to make here in the db2 code...Am I suppose to make a composite key in the employee table with emp_num and manager_num? or am I suppose to somehow make a composite foreign key in the campus table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the error message literally.  In order to have a foreign key, you must reference something in the parent table that will return exactly one record.  You are trying to reference manager_num which is not only not unique, but could actually be null.  That's why db2 is barking at you.

Comment: okay so it works when I make Manager_Num the primary key, however, EMP_NUM is suppose to be the primary key of the employee table because this script is being created based off the professor's assignment 1 solution, which are the tables we have to use with the set primary and foreign keys. So I'm at a total loss, I even tried putting NOT NULL at the manager_num in the employee table.

Comment: Your foreign key should reference EMP_NUM, not MANAGER_NUM. I'm guessing MANAGER_NUM is itself a foreign key, referencing the same EMP_NUM. By the way, why are your supposedly numeric and date fields defined as VARCHAR(10)?

Comment: i just got it just before i saw your message lol! I didn't notice that manager_num is referencing to the same emp_num because my professor had written it differently.

and I'm using varchar, because this script is basically for multiple daycare's where the for example campus id/emp_num can be a combination of letters and numbers.

So i figured varchar would be best? As for the date field, it wasn't described in the assignment if the date will be written as 02/12/2013 or as December 2 2013....so i thought varchar would be best for that as well.

Comment: I would probably add an specific id column that is numeric and use it internally. The alpha numeric ids can be just an attribute like first_name and last_name and used when presenting the data to the end user. The same is true for the date fields. Here you should store your date in a native data format and convert it to the desired format whenever you present the data to the end user.

Comment: @PeterSchuetze I made the corrections now, thank you.

Question though, how do I create two primary keys in a table, where both primary keys are foreign keys to two separate tables, and where one of the foreign keys has not been previously created?

Example:
Registered_Authorized_Adults [FamID, AuthorizedAdult#]
FK FamID --> Registration_Form
FK AuthorizedAdult# --> Adults,

FamID already exists, but AuthorizedAdult# does not in Adults, but Adult# does, however they are two different things, where Authorized one is like emergency contact. I duno how to put that into db2 script.

Comment: @Umeed: looks like a new question, please post it as a new question. BTW, there can only be one primary key per Table. You can have as many foreign keys as you want on table.

Comment: okay thanks for the heads up! if im still stuck i'll post a new question!